# Firefox add-on for examining z-indexes

Tags: css, firefox, firebug, firefox-addon

I'm working on a fairly large site and am having trouble managing z-indexes.  Is there a Firefox add-on that will look at a page and give me an ordered list of every element with a z-index declared?  That would save a ton of times for the cases where a z-index was wrong or hard to find.

Comment: I found this usefull: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/visualizing-your-z-index-stacks-with-jquery/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You find it here

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

When you have installed the Web Developer Extension, choose from its menu

```
Information > Display Topographic information
```

Comment: How do I examine a list of elements with z-indexes using Web Developer?

Comment: There usually is a web developer toolbar, click Information, then display Element information, a little red box will appear around the element you are hovering, click it and a little yellow box will appear in the top left corner with all the attribute that element carries. Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F.

Comment: ALso, in the same information dorpdown, click "Display stack levels".

Comment: Awesome!  "Display stack levels" was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's a great tool, I use it allll the time, It's automatic for me to fire up the site I Work on and hit ctrl+shif+f straight away! Glad it helped you.

Comment: Nice one, unfortunately in "crowded" layouts (i.e. web gis) it becomes useless as the information displays overlapped and mostly unreadable)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use FireBug http://getfirebug.com/
You can examine you whole dom including z-indexes.

Use a little javascript to help you find all elements with z-indexes: 
1. load jquery 
2. insert this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//replacethis by the elemets that could have a z index ('div, span, etc..')
$('replacethis').each(function(){ 
 if ($(this).css('z-index')) {
  var zindex = $(this).css('z-index')
  if (window.console) {
   console.log($(this), zindex)
  }else{
   $(this).css('border', '1px solid red').prepend('<strong>' + zindex +'</strong>')
  }
 }; 

}); 
</script>
```

if your the firebug console is not loaded it will give a red border to all the elements with a z-index and perpend the z-index value to the box.

Comment: I do use FireBug, but it doesn't have a view that shows only elements that have declared z-indexes right?

Comment: thats right yeah, but by clicking on the element you can see if there is a z-index or not. Use firebug and use a little javascript that helps you find all elements with z indexes:

1. load jquery
2. insert this javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
//replacethis by the elemets that could have a z index ('div, span, etc..')
$('replacethis').each(function(){
  if ($(this).css('z-index')) {
  console.log($(this))
}
})
</script>

make sure your firebug console is on

Answer (score 0):

Very old question at this point, but in case anybody else comes by this way, there is still (huh, 'still'... not sure if it existed when the question was posted originally or not) a Firefox add-on called 'Tilt 3D' that offers a 3D view of a webpage and is excellent for diagnosing z-index issues.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tilt/

Firefox even had the same feature embedded in some kind of preview form for a few versions but later removed it. The above add-on has not been updated since 2011, but still works for the time being. **Health warning though**: multi-process support in Firefox is progressively coming to life with successive Firefox versions, and this add-on does not work with multi-process (also referred to as Electrolysis or just 'e10s') support enabled. More information here:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis